# Twitter bootstrap grid hack

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm stuck with a design decision using bootstrap grid.

The page is split in 2 columns.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5">
       <!-- content -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-1">
       <img />
       <!-- content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

On desktop screens I want an image displayed at the top of the right column when this collapses to phone size, I want the image to start at the top of the page instead of midway down.

My initial idea is to have the same image at the top of both columns, then toggle display:none respectively, loading the same image twice seems like a bad practice to me.

Can I ask if there would be a better way or is my method ok?

Comment: Just an FYI, Bootstrap 3 has column ordering functionality, where you can push and pull columns based on the screen size. This would solve your problem very easily.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, that is what i was trying to acheive with offset i didnt realise there was a different class for it :)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap does offer the classes `hidden-*` which you can find [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes).

With these classes you could create separate divs for displaying content on a mobile and on a desktop.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well it's one of the included parts of Bootstrap and it's as easy as doing `<div class="hidden-xs"><!-- Display image for non-mobiles --></div>`.

Comment: Its not included with the customised version, Its an additional 10kb spread over alot of code. My only question was is loading the same image twice bad practice, or shall I do that and just implement my own media query toggle.